# Displaying two arrays in tester class

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have six tasks that need to be completed but i do not know how to display them. I haave all the code to calculate each task needed but when it comes to applying them to my tester class i am stuck. below is my code for the original class. these are the task that need to be done:

1. Display the original data set, as shown in the table.
2. The average profit for the supermarket chain.
3. The city with the highest profit.
4. A list of all the cities with profit at, or above the average.
5. The cities and their profit listed in descending order of the profits.
6. Make a horizontal graph showing the performance of each supermarket

Please help because ive been doing this for the last couple days and still havent been able to do anything... i must be stupid please help

```
package supermarkets;

public class Supermarkets 
{

    private String[] city = {"Miami", "Sunrise", "Hollywood",
        "Tallahassee", "Jacksonville", "Orlando", "Gainesville", "Pensacola",
        "Ocala", "Sebring"};

    private double[] profit = {10200000, 14600000, 17000000, 6000000,
        21600000, 9100000, 8000000, 12500000, 2000000, 4500000};

    public Supermarkets(String[] c, double[] p)
    {
        //array for the city
        city = new String[c.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < c.length; i++)
            city[i] = c[i];


        //array for the profits
        profit = new double[p.length];
        for(int i = 0; i < p.length; i++)
            profit[i] = p[i];
    }


    //sums up the profits from the cities
    public double sumArray()
    {
        double sum = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < profit.length; i++)
            sum = sum + profit [i];

        return sum;
    }

    //calculates the average of the profits from the cities
    public double average()
    {
        return sumArray() / profit.length;
    }


    //shows highest profit
    double findHighestProfit() 
    {
        double highest = profit[0];

        for(int i = 1; i < profit.length; i++)
        {
            if ( profit [i] > highest )
                highest = profit [i];      
        }
        return highest;
    }


    //gives the above average profit
    public String aboveAvarage()
    {
        String s = "";
        double avg = average();
        for (int i = 0; i < profit.length; i++)
            if (profit [i] > avg)
                s = s + city[i] + "  " + profit[i] + "\n";
        return s;
    }


    //creates a graph showing city and profits
    public String makeGraph()
    {
        String s = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < profit.length; i++)
        {
            s = s + city[i] + " ";
            int x = (int) Math.floor( profit[i] );

            for(int j = 1; j <=x; j++)
                s = s + "*";
            s = s + "\n";
        }
        return s;
    }


    //resets profits position from least to greatest
    public int findPosition(int startScanFrom)
    {
        int position = startScanFrom;

        for (int i = startScanFrom + 1; i < profit.length; i++)
            if (profit[i] < profit[position])
                position = i;

        return position;
    }

    //swaps values for city and profits
    public void swap(int i, int j)
    {
        // Swap the profits
        double temp = profit[i];
        profit[i] = profit[j];
        profit[j] = temp;

        // Swap the cities
        String str = city[i];
        city[i] = city[j];
        city[j] = str;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just System.out.println(sumArray()); ?  and similarly for everything else.  What are you stumbling on here?

If you don't know how to get the tester to work more like -

(in tester main)
Supermarket sm = new SuperMarket();
System.out.println(sm.sumArray());

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide your test/driver program, so I had to make a lot of assumptions.

1. Just write a method that loops through the two arrays and prints the values.
2. Your method to find the average profit looks fine.
3. You have a method to find the highest profit, but you need to display the city.  I added a method to find the city with the highest profit.

   ```
   //shows city with highest profit
   String findHighestProfitCity() 
   {
       double highest = profit[0];
       String c = city[0];

       for(int i = 1; i < profit.length; i++)
       {
           if ( profit [i] > highest ) {
               highest = profit [i]; 
               c = city[i];
           }
       }
       return c;
   }
   ```
4. This is a fairly straightforward method.  Once you calculate the average, just loop through the city/profit arrays and display any cities that have a profit higher than the average.
5. The easiest way to do this with the data organized in two arrays would be to write a custom sort routine that sorts the profit array and makes a swap in the city array each time one is necessary in profit.
6. The test data you put in your city and profit arrays is way too big to display graphically.  Your `makeGraph()` method tries to draws `x` asterisks for each value in profit.  Even after cutting five zeroes off of each value, that still didn't fit on my screen, so I modifed that method to only draw `x/10` asterisks for each profit

   ```
   for(int j = 1; j <= x/10; j++)
       s = s + "*";
   ```

Here's a test/driver program that you can use as a starting point.

```
package supermarkets;

public class SupermarketDriver {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String[] cities = {"Miami", "Sunrise", "Hollywood",
            "Tallahassee", "Jacksonville", "Orlando", "Gainesville", "Pensacola",
            "Ocala", "Sebring"};

    double[] profits = {102, 146, 170, 60, 216, 91, 80, 125, 20, 45};


    Supermarkets sm = new Supermarkets(cities, profits);
    System.out.println(sm.makeGraph());
    System.out.println("Average profit: " + sm.average());
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Highest profit city: " + sm.findHighestProfitCity() + ", " + sm.findHighestProfit());

    }

}
```